# Not getting proper sinusoidal waveforms of the signals using MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I want to plot sinusoidal waveforms of the signals using MATLAB. I have added my code. I want to get proper sine waveforms for signals x(t),y(t),z(t) and m(t).

Waveform of x(t) is somewhat look perfect but for others **the top and bottom end part are not sinusoidal** (if you zoom it to some extent they look like triangular or spikes).

What corrections are required in the code part?

```
clc;
clear all;
close all;

figure,
w=0:0.02:pi;
x=10*sin(10*w);
%subplot(2,2,1),
plot(w,x),grid on
title('x(t)');
xlabel('t');
ylabel('x(t)');

figure,
w=0:0.02:pi;
y=20*sin(20*w);
%subplot(2,2,2),
plot(w,y),grid on
title('y(t)');
xlabel('t');
ylabel('y(t)');

figure,
w=0:0.02:pi;
z=30*sin(30*w);
%subplot(2,2,3),
plot(w,z),grid on
title('z(t)');
xlabel('t');
ylabel('z(t)');

figure,
w=0:0.02:pi;
m=10*sin(10*w)+20*sin(20*w)+30*sin(30*w);
plot(w,m),grid on
title('m(t)');
xlabel('t');
ylabel('m(t)');
```

Answer (score 2):

Just increase the step size of the x axis. As an example replace '`w=0:0.02:pi;`' with '`w=0:pi/1024:pi;`' (pi/1024=0.0031). This will give you a smoother output.